# Express JS map /$metadata

Tags: node.js, sapui5

In my UI5 application I am using ODataModel. The model is getting data from nodeJS server. First request of `oDataModel` is getting metadata, which looks like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/$metadata
```

I am unable to map the path in my router.

I tried:

```
app.get('$metadata', (req, res) => {
});

app.get('/$metadata', (req, res) => {
});

app.get('/metadata', (req, res) => {
});
```

It is working with

```
app.get('*metadata', (req, res) => {
});
```

But I'd like to avoid that.
How should the mapping be defined?

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the dollar sign between regular and square brackets ([ and ]). Example:

```
/odata/$metadata
```

would be

```
app.get('/odata/([\$])metadata', (req, res)=>{
  //your code
})
```

Using a dollar sign unescaped will be interpreted as the end of the string.

[Source](https://expressjs.com/tr/guide/routing.html)